# How to stop webpack-dev-server from comand line

Tags: java, node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

`Ctrl+C` is **not** option because i need to stop running instance on remote Linux server. I tried with `kill -9` but i did not know the PID so if any of you have any advice i will appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try to find the PID with `ps`, `top`, or `htop`?  You could probably kill it directly through `top` or `htop` as well.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the help but can i stop it if i don't know the PID, i mean if PID is `-` ? @zero298